# K Nearest Neighbours From Scratch Implementation Taking Too Long to Run

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, classification, knn

I've attempted to implement K Nearest Neighbours from scratch, in python and apply the adults income dataset (~30k rows) however, it runs infinitely... I'm not sure what I've done wrong (still quite new to all this).

I suspect it may be due to the amount of features present (14 before one-hot-encoding)?

I'd appreciate any help on this. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code and what I've tried so far. As stated above, it runs infinitely, seemingly at least - I let it run for 15 min with no outcome.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import warnings
from collections import Counter
import random


accuracies = []

for i in range(2):
    def k_nearest_neighbours(data, predict, k=3):
        if len(data) >= k:
            warnings.warn("WARNING: the number of features exceeds the chosen value of k.")
        distances = []
        for group in data:
            for feature in data[group]:
                euclidean_distance = np.linalg.norm(np.array([feature]) - np.array([predict]))
                distances.append([euclidean_distance, group])

            votes = [i[1] for i in sorted(distances)[:k]]
            vote_result = Counter(votes).most_common(1)[0][0]
            confidence = Counter(votes).most_common(1)[0][1] / k

        return vote_result, confidence


    # importing data
    df = pd.read_csv('adult.data')

    # all column titles and values within columns have a leading space, so will remove.
    df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
    df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype == 'object' else x)

    # several columns have observations of '?' - replacing with 'unknown' or 'other' as there are many of them and removing would sacrifice a good chunk of data.
    df['workclass'].replace('?', 'Unknown', inplace=True)
    df['occupation'].replace('?', 'Other', inplace=True)
    df['native_country'].replace('?', 'Unknown', inplace=True)

    # 'fnlwgt' is an id and doesnt serve to predict so it will be dropped.
    df.drop(['fnlwgt'], axis=1, inplace=True)

    # Income is our predictor so will label-encode with 0 or 1
    df['income'].replace('<=50K', 0, inplace=True)
    df['income'].replace('>50K', 1, inplace=True)

    # Normalising and one-hot-encoding numerical and categorical features, respectively.
    str_features = ['workclass', 'education', 'marital_status', 'occupation', 'relationship', 'race', 'sex', 'native_country']

    str_encoded = pd.DataFrame()
    for feature in str_features:
        encoded_feature = pd.get_dummies(df[feature], prefix=feature, drop_first=True)
        str_encoded = pd.concat([str_encoded, encoded_feature], axis=1)

    int_features = ['age', 'education_num', 'capital_gain', 'capital_loss', 'hours_per_week']

    int_normalised = df[int_features].copy()
    for feature in int_features:
        min_val = df[feature].min()
        max_val = df[feature].max()
        int_normalised[feature] = (df[feature] - min_val) / (max_val - min_val)

    processed_df = pd.concat([str_encoded, int_normalised, df['income']], axis=1)
    full_data = processed_df.astype(float).values.tolist()
    random.shuffle(full_data)


    # Performing a test/train split
    test_size = 0.2

    # Dictionaries to populate - Note: we're using dictionaries as our algorithm is designed to want a dictionary.
    train_set = {0:[], 1:[]} # dictionary mapping of lists associated with both classes; 0 (<=50K) and 1 (>50K) for training.
    test_set = {0:[], 1:[]} # Same as above but for test split.

    # Multiplying the 'test_size = 0.2' by the length of full data to create an index value and then we slice it based on that index value, which is converted to a whole number with 'int' - essentially, grabbing the first 80% of the rows.
    train_data = full_data[:-int(test_size*len(full_data))]
    test_data = full_data[-int(test_size*len(full_data)):] # Like above but slicing for the last 20% of data

    # Populating the dictionaries
    for i in train_data:
        train_set[i[-1]].append(i[:-1]) # searches for last element in each row and based on that appends it to the corresponding mapping in train_set
    for i in test_data:
        test_set[i[-1]].append(i[:-1]) # same as above but for test_set

    correct = 0
    total = 0

    # looping through each group/class in the test set, and then looping through each datapoint in each group, which is then fed into the KNN algorithm.
    for group in test_set:
        for data in test_set[group]:
            vote, confidence = k_nearest_neighbours(train_set, data, k=25)
            if group == vote:
                correct += 1
            total += 1
        print(f'The total accuracy is {correct/total}')
        accuracies.append(correct/total)

print(f'\n The averaged accuracy was: {sum(accuracies)/len(accuracies)}')
```

Comment: Why not using scikit-learn which has an implementation of KNN?

Comment: I wanted to test my knowledge and see if i could do it from scratch.

Comment: A lot of existing implementations use C/C++ under the hood. I am not sure how `pandas`, but `numpy` certainly does, think about how to use it. Even if you manage to optimize your code, you probably won't get even close to speed of existing out-of-box solutions, such as `scikit-learn`.

Comment: @MartinBenes Thanks for your reply - my goal wasn't for it to be high performant, rather to see if I could challenge myself and make it work. Scikit-learn would undoubtedly be much faster but i felt (given that I'm learning how the algorithm works) that a from-scratch implementation would be a good thing to try and test my knowledge.

Comment: If you don't want it to be highly efficient, then why not run it with smaller inputs first? What are the results then?

Comment: @trincot Thanks for your reply - I have done it from scratch, twice and on two smaller datasets: the breast cancer and iris dataset. I wanted to see if I could tackle something larger.

Comment: Then the above comments apply. It is expected that the larger the input is the more need there is for effeciy

Comment: @trincot was definitely expecting a longer runtime but is 15 min or greater really expected? I know that with KNN, it shouldn't have any big issues performing on datasets <1gb. But of course, maybe I'm wrong. Still learning.